# Funciones predefinidas

Tags: base-de-datos, postgresql, postgresql-13

Buenas estoy con clases de funciones predefinidas ( aun no nos enseñan como crear una) el ejercicio es el siguiente:

Dadas dos cadenas, crea una nueva cadena igual a la primera sin la aparición de la segunda. Si aparece más de una vez, sólo se suprimirá la primera aparición.

Ejemplo 1: `'text1 text1 text1'  = 'text1 text1'`

Ejemplo 2: `'text1 text1' = 'text1'`

Alguna función que aplique con estos dos casos ?

Comment: dónde están las dos cadenas en tu ejemplo? Estás mostrando sólo una cadena de 2 o más palabras

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pudiera utilizar las familia de funciones `TRIM`:

por ejemplo:

```sql
db=# SELECT ltrim('text1 text1 text1' ,'text1');
    ltrim     
--------------
  text1 text1
(1 row)

db=# SELECT rtrim('text1 text1 text1' ,'text1');
    rtrim     
--------------
 text1 text1 
(1 row)
```

Te recomiendo leer la documentación de las funciones de trabajo de cadena
https://www.postgresql.org/docs/12/functions-string.html

Comment: Muchas gracias ! si que habia leido esa docu pero no caia que con el ltrim podia hacerlo.